# How can tcpdump monitor TCP disconnect and log timedate stamp?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I have two servers each running a Java application that creates two separate TCP connections, one from HostA -> HostB and one from HostB -> HostA on separate ports.

I am told the TCP connection is lost and re-established, but the client is unable to provide me the time and date of when it happens.

Can I setup tcpdump on HostA to monitor the specific port purely to tell me when it disconnects?  Same for HostB connection?  I dont care about payload data etc.

I looked at the man page, found some HowTo's online, google searched, etc.  I didnt see examples of what I am looking for.  Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

"Disconnecting" in TCP actually involves each host saying "I have nothing more to send" and the other host acknowledging that; when both hosts have done that, the connection is closed.  See [Closing a Connection in RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5).

As Nath noted, a connection can also be forcibly closed with a "reset" indication.

So what you're looking for are the FINs that indicate "I have nothing more to say" and the RSTs that indicate "I don't have a connection like that".  You'd want to run tcpdump with a filter that looks for traffic to or from the specific port and that has the FIN flag set.  With current versions of libpcap/WinPcap, you could use a filter such as

```
tcp port XXX and (tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-fin|tcp-rst)) != 0
```

with XXX being the port number.  Note that, for a clean close, this will capture multiple packets, as each side has to send a "I have no more data to send" indication.

This will, unfortunately, not work with IPv6, just with IPv4.

Comment: Your answer doesn't cover connections ending with  RST you should catch these aswell

Comment: "Your answer doesn't cover connections ending with RST" Updated.